# PHP storing $obj->key in mysql table for use in page

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

I am trying to use preg_replace for a letter template to generate letters with dynamic content. My concept is to store the pattern any the object reference in the databases so I can build my pattern and replace arrays on the fly without "hard coding" them in the page. Below are the tables and code I am using:

```
**Table people
id || first || last**
1 || john || smith
2 || mark || stone

**Table address
Id || people_id || mailing1**
1 || 1 || 123 fake street
2 || 2 || 34 melrose place

**Table macros
id || pattern || replace**
1 || first || $people->first
2 || last || $people->last
3 || mailing1 || $address->mailing1

//Set variables
$thePerson = $_POST['people_id'];
$theString = '<p>Dear {first} {last},</p><p>I am writing regarding your home at {mailing1}</p>';
$replacements = array();
$patterns = array();
$counter = 0;
//Get people information
$peopleSQL = $conn_read->prepare('SELECT * FROM people WHERE people.id=:people_id;');
$peopleSQL->execute(array(':people_id' => $thePerson));
$people = $peopleSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//Get address information
$addressSQL = $conn_read->prepare('SELECT * FROM address WHERE address.people_id=:people_id;');
$peopleSQL->execute(array(':people_id' => $thePerson));
$people = $peopleSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//Build macros for preg_replace
$macrosSQL = $conn_read->prepare('SELECT * FROM macros;');
$macrosSQL->execute();
while ($macros = $macrosSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $patterns[$counter] = '/\{'.$macros->pattern.'\}/';
    $replacements[$counter] = $$macros->replace;
    $counter++;
}
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $theString);
```

For output assume $thePerson is set to 1. The output I am getting from this code is:

> "Dear $people->first $people->last,
>
> I am writing regarding your home at $address->mailing1"

Where the desired output would be:

> "Dear john smith,
>
> I am writing regarding your home at 123 fake street"

I get that the $macro->replace is coming out of the database as a string and being treated as such and that is why I am seeing the result I am seeing, but I am hoping there is a way to handle this, or some syntax that will give me the desired result. The research I have done kept turning up the eval() function, but I am not familiar with that at all and everyone says not to use it.

Thanks in advance for any direction on this as I am at a loss. Also if someone has a completely different way to handle this I am more than open to suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler way.  Maybe you need more complexity but for this example you don't.

```
$thePerson = $_POST['people_id'];
$theString = '<p>Dear {first} {last},</p><p>I am writing regarding your home at {mailing1}</p>';

$sql = $conn_read->prepare("
SELECT p.first AS `{first}`, p.last AS `{last}`, a.mailing1 AS `{mailing1}`
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN address a ON a.people_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = :people_id
");
$sql->execute(array(':people_id' => $thePerson));

$results = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$output = str_replace(array_keys($results), array_values($results), $theString);
```

Notice how I avoided using the macros table at all, by simply naming my fields for the sql result set to be the values of `$theString` that need replacing, and only selecting those fields instead of everything with `select *`.  Also, since it's just a string replace and doesn't need regex fanciness, I switched `preg_replace` for the simpler and faster `str_replace`.

In some cases like if you have unrelated tables you might need to use two queries.  So you can just do the `str_replace` twice (make sure to use `$output` as the third parameter if you do so).

Comment: Nice! I was thinking I could do some sweet select but could conceptualize the syntax. Feel free to hit me up if you need anything mike at myk12 dot org.

Comment: @Johannes brings up a good point, you can store `$theString` in a table, along with its query, if you need to make a lot of different mailing templates/queries.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you shouldn't store any of the object-references in a database, because you don't need them: If you don't want to do any 'hardcoding' why you want to store the object-reference if they won't change? - I guess you won't store each day an absolutely different dataset in your object, so you can make this fix in your code.

At first you have to collect all data of the person in one array which shouldn't be too hard for you. Then you create two arrays one for searching one for replacing and use `str_replace($search, $replace, $string)`, because you know every key in `$theString` and you know which data should be inserted instead.

```
$person = new person($_POST["people_id"]);    // I don't know if you know this kind of coding (OOP)... but you could also do your MySQL-queries to create an array storing all data you need
$theString = "<p>Dear {first} {last},</p><p>I am writing regarding your home at {mailing1}</p>";

$search = array(
    "{first}",
    "{last}",
    "{mailing1}",
);
$replace = array(
    $person->first,
    $person->last,
    $person->mailing1,
);

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $theString);
```

What you can do is to store `$theString`'s value in a database so you can change the letter-content fast...